# How to move my blog to my domain name

Tags: blogging

I'm not a technical person but I want to know how I can move my blog to my domain name.  Can anyone please provide step-by-step process to get this done?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your server configuration is configured.

If you host the website from an IP you control:
 - Go to your domain registrar's website and update the DNS controls. Change the A (Host) record to point to your blog's webserver's IP address.

Otherwise:
 - Go to your domain registrar's website and forward the domain to your blog url